# My setTimeout function doesnt work and I dont know why?

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, settimeout

I'm making a function that displays a window when all the inpuit boxes have info and I want the new window to close after 5 seconds but my setTimeout doesnt work

```
            function processInput()
            {
                //if statement checks if all fields contain something
                //or true, if not they are falsy
                if(nameInput.value && phoneNumber.value && adress.value)
                {
                    //New Window size and centering
                    let winWidth = 300;
                    let winHeight = 300;
                    let leftPosition = ((screen.width - winWidth)/2);
                    let topPosition = ((screen.height - winHeight)/2);

                    //String that contains onptions for the new Window
                    let options = "width =" + winWidth + ",height=" 
                                + winHeight + ", left =" + leftPosition
                                + ", top =" + topPosition;
                    //creates a new window
                    let confWindow = window.open("confirm.htm", 
                    "Confirm Page", options);

                    //Setting a timer for the new window to close after 
                    //5 seconds
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        confWindow.close();
                    }, 5000);

                    //making the new window the main window
                    //confWindow.focus();
                }
                else{
                    window.alert("Please Enter Information in all fields");
                }
```

Comment: Are you sure the setTimeout gets set? Maybe add some console logs just before calling it, and within the callback function, then you can see where the issue is. Also the issue is probably with scoping. It should work if you use "var confWindow", instead of "let".

Comment: Your code works for me. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: You have to be clearer about what "doesn't work" means. What have you done so far to investigate the problem? Are you certain that the `setTimeout()` call even happens?

Comment: @Ood Why would `var` work any better than `let`? The nested function is in the `if`, so it's in the same scope.

Comment: No there aren't any errors. Btw I think what you mean by that my code works on your end is that the window just gets covered by the main window but it doesnt close.

Comment: @Barmar You are correct. Without any logs and knowing where the code breaks, I assumed it must be a scoping issue, but I can see that it is not the case.

Comment: Did you verify whether the setTimeout callback runs?

Answer (score -3):

For me, it works if you add one more **}** at the end of the file